# How can I change the @ symbol in e-mail addresses?

Tags: fonts, symbols, urls

I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{mailto:e.xmaple@example.com}{e.xmaple@example.com}
\end{document}
```

This way I can write an email address, but I don't like the shape of the @ symbol inserted by LaTeX:

[image: Computer Modern @]

How can I get it to look like [image: Word @]?

Comment: Could you please be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol

Comment: I have no authority to affix a image. There exists difference between @ made by latex and @ made by word, I like the word type @.

Comment: Did you try the with `\MVAt` command with `\usepackage{marvosym}` in the preamble? I just found it via Detexify

Comment: @percusse,the package works,thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The @ symbol you get is dependent on the font you use. As you note, the standard Computer Modern @ is quite different from e.g. the one in Times.  So you can define your own macro to insert the @ from a different font, and then choose whichever @ you like best.

Here's an example of substituting the Times font itself (with Computer Modern below for comparison). Another reasonable alternative is Charter (`\fontfamily{bch}`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\newcommand*\myat{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont @}}
\begin{document}
\Large
% Charter
\href{mailto:foo@bar}{foo\myat bar}

% Computer Modern
\href{mailto:foo@bar}{foo@bar}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Some people may tell you that you shouldn't switch fonts for a single symbol like this, since the relative weights of the fonts look different, (as you can see from the image above) but for most purposes this may not be an issue.

For a list of most of the commonly installed fonts and their internal names see this question:

[How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693)

Comment: It doesn't work inside equation.

Comment: @John If you load `amsmath` you can use `\myat` within the `\text{...}` command. If you want to change it in the math font directly, that's more complicated. See e.g. [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)